# How do I check collision of a rectangle and a previous position of a rectangle in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a Tron game (https://www.classicgamesarcade.com/game/21670/tron-game.html) and need to check on all racers if they are colliding with each other.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screenWidth = 500
screenHeight = 500
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))
#both width and height of the characters
radius = 5
#amount of change in the x or y of the characters every frame
vel = 5

pygame.display.set_caption("Tron")


class character(object):
    #'direction' is the direction the character will move
    #'keyBinds' are the keys that can change the direction
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, direction, keyBinds):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.direction = direction
        self.keyBinds = keyBinds

    #changes the direction the character moves
    def changeDirection(self, keys):
        #only changes when the right key was pressed and the character isn't already moving the opposite direction
        if keys[self.keyBinds[0]] and self.direction != 'r': 
            self.direction = 'l'
        elif keys[self.keyBinds[1]] and self.direction != 'l':
            self.direction = 'r'
        elif keys[self.keyBinds[2]] and self.direction != 'd':
            self.direction = 'u'
        elif keys[self.keyBinds[3]] and self.direction != 'u':
            self.direction = 'd'

    def move(self, vel):
        if self.direction == 'l':
            self.x -= vel
        elif self.direction == 'r':
            self.x += vel
        elif self.direction == 'u':
            self.y -= vel
        elif self.direction == 'd':
            self.y += vel

    #returns True if the character should be dead
    def checkDead(self, radius, screenWidth, screenHeight):
        #check if the character is out of bounds
        if (self.x < 0) or (self.x + radius > screenWidth) or (self.y < 0) or (self.y + radius > screenWidth):
            return True
        #check if the character has collided WIP


#makes a list with characters
chars = [
    character(480, 250, (255,0,0), 'l', (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN)),
    character(20, 250, (0,255,0), 'r', (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d, pygame.K_w, pygame.K_s))
    ]
run = True

#main loop
while run:
    #makes the loop run 30 times a second
    clock.tick(30)

    #closes the window, if 'X' is pressed
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    #logs all keys being pressed in a list I think xd
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #closes the window, if there are no characters left in 'chars'
    if len(chars) > 0:
        #runs all object functions of every character in 'chars'
        for char in chars:
            char.changeDirection(keys)
            char.move(vel)
            #draws a rectangle representing the charater
            pygame.draw.rect(win, char.color, (char.x, char.y, radius, radius))
            #removes the character from 'chars' if checkDead returns True
            if char.checkDead(radius, screenWidth, screenHeight):
                chars.pop(chars.index(char))
    else:
        run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

With just 2 racers (called characters in my code), I could just use a bunch of if statements to check if the position of their hit boxes match, but I'm planning on adding up to 8 more racers later on so I think that isn't a good option.

**Now comes a bigger problem though.
As in classic Tron, I need to have the previous positions of racers count for collisions as well.**

That aside, I always appreciate tips on how I can improve my code, so if you see anything you would handle differently, please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Changed the title from: How do I check rectangle collisions of multiple objects in Pygame? to: How do I check collision of a rectangle and a previous position of a rectangle in Pygame?, because the main question has already been answered in a different post but there are still side questions to be answered.
Also, in my structure of my code, the collision check would be in checkDead()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, Tron is a grid based game, so an easy solution is to just keep a list of points/tiles that are alreay "taken", and then check if a player is trying to move to an already taken tile.

```
...
painted = set()
...
class character(object):
    ...
    #returns True if the character should be dead
    def checkDead(self, radius, screenWidth, screenHeight, painted):
        #check if the character is out of bounds
        if (self.x < 0) or (self.x + radius > screenWidth) or (self.y < 0) or (self.y + radius > screenWidth):
            return True

        #check if the character has collided WIP
        return (char.x / radius, char.y / radius) in painted

...
while run:
    ...
    #closes the window, if there are no characters left in 'chars'
    if len(chars) > 0:
        #runs all object functions of every character in 'chars'
        for char in chars:
            char.changeDirection(keys)
            char.move(vel)
            #removes the character from 'chars' if checkDead returns True
            if char.checkDead(radius, screenWidth, screenHeight, painted):
                chars.pop(chars.index(char))

        for char in chars:
            painted.add((char.x / radius, char.y / radius))

        for char in chars:
            #draws a rectangle representing the charater
            pygame.draw.rect(win, char.color, (char.x, char.y, radius, radius))
```

Note that this works because you move one tile per frame. If you decide to let your players move more than one tile per frame, you'll have to add those extra tiles to the `painted` set, too.

Of course there are a lot of different ways to do this differently. For example, you could check the part of the screen you're going to draw the rect for any non-black pixels. Or you could store all rects you draw to the screen in a list and use `Rect.colliderect` to check for collisions (probably slow). So let's keep it simple.